# MVC Grid get value from another table using id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I am using Telerik MVC Grid, have two tables:

```
  public partial class Sleep
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string PHN { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Day { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SleepLevelId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SDuration { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public virtual SleepLevel SleepLevel { get; set; }
    }

  public partial class SleepLevel
{
    public SleepLevel()
    {
        this.Sleep = new HashSet<Sleep>();
    }

    public int SleepLevelId { get; set; }
    public string TheLevel { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Sleep> Sleep { get; set; }
}
```

}

I use the second model for dropdownlist.  Here how I generate the Grid Model:

```
private IEnumerable<Sleep> GePB ()
            {
             ....
            var sleep = db.Sleep.Include(s => s.SleepLevel).Where(d => d.PHN == phn && d.Day <= toDate);     
            return sleep;
            }
        [GridAction]
        public ActionResult _AjaxBinding ()
            {
            return View(new GridModel<Sleep>   {  Data = GePB()  });
            }
```

In the Grid I use:

```
 @(Html.Telerik().Grid<Sleep>()
                  .Name("Grid")
                  .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(p => p.ID))
                  .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert().ButtonType(GridButtonType.ImageAndText).ImageHtmlAttributes(new
                  {
                      style = "margin-left:0;"
                  }))
                  .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
                      .Select("_SelectAjaxEditing", "Sleep")
                              .Insert("_InsertAjaxEditing", "Sleep")
                              .Update("_SaveAjaxEditing", "Sleep")
                              .Delete("_DeleteAjaxEditing", "Sleep"))
                  .Columns(columns =>
                  {
                      columns.Bound(p => p.Day).Width(70).Format("{0:d}");
                      columns.Bound(o => o.SleepLevel.TheLevel).Width(70);
        columns.Bound(o => o.SDuration).Width(70);
        columns.Command(commands =>
        {
        commands.Edit().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image);
        commands.Delete().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image);
        }).Width(50).Title("Edit");
        })
        .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
        .Pageable()
        .Scrollable()
        .Sortable().Filterable()
        )
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to get property 'TheLevel' of undefined or null reference
```

Would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Can you show the definition of SleepLevel?

Comment: What do you mean by the definition of SleepLevel? thanks

Comment: I mean the class definition of SleepLevel, as used as the seventh property in the Sleep class, and as per your grid call

columns.Bound(o => o.SleepLevel.TheLevel).Width(70);

Unless you have errors in both calls and meant to use StressLevel

Comment: It is defined in public enum StressLevel.  I am using EF 6.1.

Comment: OK then you will have to share the grid binding code you use on your view.

Answer (score 0):

There is no property in the Sleep class that is a S**tress**Level type. So I'll address the error message as best as possible.

The error

> Unable to get property 'TheLevel' of undefined or null reference

is because this line
`columns.Bound(o => o.SleepLevel.TheLevel).Width(70);`

is trying to access a property of the SleepLevel class called TheLevel that most probably does not exist in your Sleep class.

Comment: Can you add the class for GridModel that is used here
`return View(new GridModel<Sleep>   {  Data = GePB()  });`

Comment: Disregard last comment, I hit enter by mistake.

I'm not sure if your grid is bound to the Sleep class properly.  From [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-data-binding-ajax-binding.html), it looks like you could simplify your code in the controller.  Try something like this:
`[GridAction]
        public ActionResult _AjaxBinding ()
            {
            return View(new GridModel(GePB());
            }`

Comment: Can you share the grid binding code that you use in your view?

Comment: Try making sure that the grid is using the methods defined in your controller.  Right now, the controller has method named _AjaxBinding(), but the grid is looking for method _SelectAjaxEditing.